# PySimpleGUI changing visibility breaks columns(?)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have 2 columns and I want to reveal them on a button press by using the visibility parameter. However, it seems that columns that go from invisible to visible stop being next to each other and are instead arranged like rows.

Here is the code without the reveal, and the columns work fine:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

left_col = sg.Column([[sg.Frame('',[],background_color = '#FF0000',size = (60,40))]])
right_col = sg.Column([[sg.Frame('',[],background_color = '#00FF00',size = (60,40))]])

layout = [
    [sg.Button('reveal')],
    [left_col,right_col]]

window = sg.Window('Converter', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

And here is the same code with the columns being revealed:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

left_col = sg.Column([[sg.Frame('',[],background_color = '#FF0000',size = (60,40))]],visible = False, key = 'left')
right_col = sg.Column([[sg.Frame('',[],background_color = '#00FF00',size = (60,40))]],visible = False, key = 'right')

layout = [
    [sg.Button('reveal')],
    [left_col,right_col]]

window = sg.Window('Converter', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'reveal':
        window['left'].update(visible = True)
        window['right'].update(visible = True)
        
window.close()
```

I guess my question is whether there is a workaround for this (or whether I did something wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements after `visible=False` will miss it's location in the window, so use function `pin` to keep the location for element if you want to set it to be invisible.

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Button('reveal')],
    [sg.pin(left_col), sg.pin(right_col)]]
```

By default, the background is the background color of theme. Of course, you can built one by yourself which with one more option `bg` as background_color.

Don't forget to set the background color of the Column in your layout at the same time.

```py
def pin(elem, vertical_alignment=None, shrink=True, expand_x=None, expand_y=None, bg=None):
    if shrink:
        return sg.Column([[elem, sg.Column([[]], pad=(0,0), background_color=bg)]], background_color=bg, pad=(0, 0), vertical_alignment=vertical_alignment, expand_x=expand_x, expand_y=expand_y)
    else:
        return sg.Column([[elem]], pad=(0, 0), vertical_alignment=vertical_alignment, expand_x=expand_x, expand_y=expand_y, background_color=bg)
```

Then you code maybe something like this

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def pin(elem, vertical_alignment=None, shrink=True, expand_x=None, expand_y=None, bg=None):
    if shrink:
        return sg.Column([[elem, sg.Column([[]], pad=(0,0), background_color=bg)]], background_color=bg, pad=(0, 0), vertical_alignment=vertical_alignment, expand_x=expand_x, expand_y=expand_y)
    else:
        return sg.Column([[elem]], pad=(0, 0), vertical_alignment=vertical_alignment, expand_x=expand_x, expand_y=expand_y, background_color=bg)


left_col = sg.Column([[sg.Frame('',  [], background_color = '#FF0000', size = (60,40))]], background_color='blue')
right_col = sg.Column([[sg.Frame('', [], background_color = '#00FF00', size = (60,40))]], background_color='blue')

layout = [
    [sg.Button('reveal')],
    [pin(left_col, bg='blue'), pin(right_col, bg='blue')]]

window = sg.Window('Converter', layout, background_color='blue')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: oh thank you, that is working. Follow up question though, I have a custom styling and pin seems to add the default background color and doesn't have a background_color parameter to customize it. Is there a way to influence it?

Comment: Update as above.